# getPage in Rfacebook package returning NA

Tags: r, facebook

While extracting data from a Facebook page using getPage function in RFacebook, it is returning NA value in the message column particularly when the type column has values "photo" or "link".

The code used so far:

```
page <- getPage(page="MAC", token, n = 5000, since = '2015/06/01',until = '2015/08/01', feed = T)

$ message       : chr  NA NA NA "Wow, MAC, you really nailed it with the Prep + Prime 24 Hour Eye Base. The best eye primer ever! :)" ...

$ type          : chr  "photo" "photo" "photo" "status" ...
```

A reproducible example:

Case 1:- "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1033785533300415&set=o.16126780553&type=1"

Case 2:- "https://www.facebook.com/BellajaeMUwho/photos/a.1485483581678756.1073741830.1448656815361433/1761689297391515/?type=1"

For Case 1, the text "Does MAC offer employee..." can be completely extracted.

For Case 2, the text "wet n wild #FergieGelLiner..." comes as NA.

Any pointers on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the post contains no text, only a photo or a link. You can check the documentation for what each of the fields means [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed).

Comment: It is able to extract the text associated with a photo or a link only in a few cases. Edited the question with an example.